# Вызов action из final form при onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

Есть некоторая страница в приложении react.js с [final form](https://final-form.org/react). Все формы работают, но там не было такого момента, что при сабмите формы понадобилось вдруг вызвать один из экшенов redux.

```
private renderFilters() {
    return (
        <Form
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => {
                return (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-inline">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                );
            }}/>
    );
}

....

private onSubmit(values: Filter) {
    this.props.filterChanded(values);
}
```

И при запуске приложения получил ошибку:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Мммм... И как тогда получить доступ к this.props в приложении? Нашёл только [упоминание](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51101038/5752652), что форме важно только то, что onSubmit должен вернуть промис, но не понимаю, как внутрь промиса прокинуть this.props, если их всё равно нет?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько это react way - сделал так:

Перенёс onSubmit в action creators

```
export const actionCreators = {
    onSubmit: (filter: Filter): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        ...
    },
```

и вызвал оттуда:

```
onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас this теряется при обработке события, необходимо биндить `this.onSubmit.bind(this)` или обернуть в стрелочную ф-ю `()=>this.onSubmit()`

[обработка событий React](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```js
private renderFilters() {
    return (
        <Form
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} //биндить надо
            render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => {
                return (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-inline">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                );
            }}/>
    );
}

....

private onSubmit(values: Filter) {
    this.props.filterChanded(values);
}
```

Comment: гм, да я вроде биндил - но уговорили, попробую ещё раз завтра глянуть.